# is this valid json schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema

is this valid json schema?

```
{
    "properties": {
        "title", "first", "last" 
    }
}
```

My point is: title, first, last don't have no specification like

```
{
    "properties": {
        "title": {}, "first": {}, "last": {} 
    }
}
```

And NOT even semicolon and {}. Is it still valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) says no:

```
Parse error on line 3:
...": {        "title",        "first", 
----------------------^
Expecting ':'
```

As described in [json-schema.org](http://json-schema.org/):

> JSON Schema is a **JSON based** format for describing JSON data.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: do you mean, json schema must be also json??

Comment: @user1592714 - Yes. The same way that XSD must be valid XML.

Comment: @user1592714 - From json-schema.org: "JSON Schema is a **JSON based format** for describing JSON data.".

Comment: Oh thank, that explains why I couldn't find "json schema validator" :)

Comment: @user1592714 Since JSON Schemas are JSON themselves, and JSON Schemas validate JSON, you actually can validate a JSON Schema against a JSON Schema. There are meta-schemas (JSON Schemas that describe JSON Schema itself) hosted at json-schema.org see http://json-schema.org/documentation.html

Answer (score 2):

This is valid:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "title": {}, "first": {}, "last": {} 
    }
}
```

Tested in Chrome Developer Tools:

```
var a = {
        "properties": {
            "title": {}, "first": {}, "last": {} 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the valid JSON

```
{
    "properties": {
        "title": {},
        "first": {},
        "last": {}
    }
}
```

Your schema is not a valid one.